# What is the end of prototype chain in JavaScript -- null or Object.prototype?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, prototype

I've been reading about the prototype chain in JavaScript and came to two slightly different definitions. It is said that every object in JavaScript has a prototype and that prototype in turn has another prototype.

The top prototype (Grand) may also have prototype and the chain can continue. Now the chain will stop at one last object. *[JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Crockford#Bibliography)* says the chain terminates at `Object.prototype` and [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) `null` is the final link where the chain terminates.

> Javascript: The Good Parts

> Every object is linked to a prototype object from which it can inherit properties. **All objects created from object literals are linked to `Object.prototype`**, an object that comes standard with JavaScript.

---

> MDN

> Each object has an internal link to another object called its prototype. That prototype object has a prototype of its own, and so on until **an object is reached with null as its prototype. null, by definition, has no prototype, and acts as the final link in this prototype chain**.

- What is the end of prototype chain in JavaScript -- null or Object.prototype? Or are `null` and `Object.prototype` one and the same thing?
- Are objects, which are not created from object literals, not linked to `Object.prototype`?
- Say I have an object `var x = { len: 4, breadth: 5}`. Would JavaScript automatically create its prototype `x.prototype`? And how long would the prototype chain be? Would `x.prototype` have only one prototype, `Object.prototype`, making a 3 point chain?
- How does JavaScript internally create automatic prototypes?

Comment: Isn't the only way to create an object which has no prototype is to use Object.create?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I don't know about `Object.create` much. I read it in JAvascript The good parts but couldn't understand it. Author used `typeof Object.create !== 'function')` But `Object.create` is already a function so I don't see how will his code get executed.

Comment: He wrote the book before Object.create was in ES5. So that if statement just checks to see if Object.create already exists.

Comment: Hmm this makes sense. Althought I still don't understand his code. I'll ask another question for that after the current doubts get cleared.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). It may help explain the prototype chain to you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. It is like, if New York has an envelope and inside, it says Colorado, and Colorado has an envelope, and inside, it says San Francisco, and San Francisco has an envelope, and inside, it says "none".  So is San Francisco end of the chain, or is "none" the end of chain?  It may depend on how you look at it.  But one thing is for sure: it points up and up the chain, for inheritance purpose (prototypal inheritance), until it reaches `null`, which means can't go further up.  And make sure you know that, to go up and up the chain, it is `__proto__`.  It is not `prototype`.
2. `Object.prototype`, `Animal.prototype` are different from `x.__proto__`.  The former are function objects (Object, Animal) having a `prototype` property pointing to a prototype object.  And `x.__proto__` is how the prototype chain is followed upward. To go up and up, it is `x.__proto__.__proto__` and so on.  See [JavaScript's Pseudo Classical Inheritance diagram](http://kenneth-kin-lum.blogspot.com/2012/10/javascripts-pseudo-classical.html) to understand it more.
3. `Object.prototype` refers to a prototype object.  [Quoted from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null), `null` "represents the intentional absence of any object value. It is one of JavaScript's primitive values."  So `Object.prototype` and `null` are not the same thing.
4. All JavaScript objects will have `obj.__proto__` referring ultimately to what `Object.prototype` refers to.  If it is not  `obj.__proto__`, then it is `obj.__proto__.__proto__`.  If not, just go up, and up, and it will reach the prototype object which `Object.prototype` refers to.  And at this point, when you go up one level (by adding a `.__proto__`, then you get `null`.  You can try it in Google Chrome's developer's tool:

   ```
   x = { a : 1 }
   > Object {a: 1}

   x.__proto__ === Object.prototype
   > true

   x.__proto__.__proto__
   > null

   Object.prototype.__proto__
   > null
   ```

Comment: Do you mean that pure objects don't have default prototypes only pure functions have?

Comment: read the whole article about the diagram first.  When you know more about `Fn.prototype` vs `obj.__proto__`, then you can ask more meaningful questions

Answer (score 4):

> What is the end of prototype chain in JavaScript ...?

Null. The **only** authority on the language is [*ECMA-262*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-the-object-prototype-object).

> Are objects, which are not created from object literals, not linked to `Object.prototype`?

They may or many not be, e.g.

```
var x = Object.create(null)
```

has a `[[Prototype]]` of null, whereas:

```
var y = {};
```

has a `[[Prototype]]` of Object.prototype.

> Say I have an object `var x = { len: 4, breadth: 5}`. Would JavaScript automatically create its prototype `x.prototype`?

No. Function objects have default *prototype* objects. Plain objects have a default `[[Prototype]]` (i.e. internal prototype property) that is *Object.prototype* (unless constructed as above).

> And how long would the prototype chain be? Would `x.prototype` have only one prototype, `Object.prototype`, making a 3 point chain?

Two values: *Object.prototype* and *null*.

> How does JavaScript internally create automatic prototypes?

However it likes, the language specification does not define implementation, only behaviour.

Comment: Was `Object.prototype` the end of chain ever or was it `null` when the language was was designed first? I mean do they have changed the end of chain form `Object.prototype` to `null` recently?

Comment: From the very beginning, see [*ECMA-262 ed 1 §15.2.4*](http://ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf) dated June 1997.

Comment: So it means _Javascript: The Good Parts _ is wrong.

Comment: But if `Object.prototype` is not the end of chain then how does every object have the method `toString` attached to it? From where is `toString` inherited?

Comment: The Good Parts is correct, an object created by an object literal inherits from Object.prototype (it would be extraordinary for Douglas Crockford to publish otherwise). It doesn't say that is the end of the chain. Hence such objects have *toString*. The only way to avoid that is per the example in the answer with `Object.create(null)`.

Comment: for "the language specification does not define implementation, only behaviour" -- actually in the case of JavaScript, the ECMA specs actually does define implementation details, which is not good

Answer (score 3):

> What is the end of prototype chain in javascript -- `null` or `Object.prototype`? Or are null and Object.prototype one and the same thing?

`null`. Consider this code in a normal JavaScript environment:

```
var o = {};
console.log(o.i_am_a_property_that_does_not_exist);
```

That property accessor operation (`o.i_am_a_property_that_does_not_exist`) ends up going to the [OrdinaryGet](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-ordinaryget) abstract operation defined by the specification with *O* set to the `o` object above and *P* set to `"i_am_a_property_that_does_not_exist"`. That operation starts like this:

1. Assert: IsPropertyKey(*P*) is true.
2. Let *desc* be ? *O*.[GetOwnProperty].
3. If *desc* is **undefined**, then

a. Let *parent* be ? *O*.[GetPrototypeOf].

b. If *parent* is **null**, return **undefined**.

c. Return ? *parent*.[[Get]](*P*, *Receiver*).

4. ...

For my example above, that [[Get]] operation in 3.c. ends up calling OrdinaryGet recursively until we run out of prototypes. As we can see, the chain ends when we reach `null`.

Moreover, it's entirely possible to have an object with a prototype chain that doesn't include `Object.prototype` at all (we'll see some in a moment). So clearly `Object.prototype` can't be the end of the prototype chain.

> Are objects, which are not created from object literals, not linked to `Object.prototype`?

The vast majority will be linked to `Object.prototype` directly or indirectly. Consider:

```
function Thing() {
}
var t = new Thing();
```

`t`'s prototype is the object referenced by `Thing.prototype`. `Thing.prototype`'s prototype is `Object.prototype`. So `t` is linked to `Object.prototype` (indirectly).

But it's entirely possible for an object *not* to be linked to `Object.prototype`. Here's one way:

```
var o = Object.create(null);
```

`Object.create` lets us create an object with the prototype we specify in the first argument (`null` in the above). So `o` above has no prototype, its [[Prototype]] internal slot (where objects remember their prototypes) is `null`.

Here's another:

```
function Thing() {
}
Thing.prototype = Object.create(null);
var t = new Thing();
```

In that case, although `t` has a prototype, its prototype's prototype is null; `t` isn't linked to `Object.prototype` at all.

> Say I have an object `var x = { len: 4, breadth: 5}`. Would JavaScript automatically create it's prototype `x.prototype`.

An object's prototype is not a property called `prototype`, so no, the JavaScript engine wouldn't create `x.prototype`. An object's prototype is linked via its [[Prototype]] internal slot, which is not directly observable but can be retrieved via `Object.getPrototypeOf`. (There's also the [legacy `__proto__` property](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__), but it's best not to use it, not least because A) It's an optional part of the specification, and B) Not all objects inherit from `Object.prototype`, which is where `__proto__` is defined.)

The `prototype` property is just used on *functions* to determine what object to use as the [[Prototype]] of new objects created via `new` with that function. Non-function objects don't have it, and if they did, it wouldn't be any more special than a property called `foo` or `bazinga`.

> And how long would the prototype chain be? Would `x.prototype` have only one prototype `Object.prototype` making a 3 point chain?

You're close, but again, the `prototype` property is not the prototype of the object, and non-function objects typically won't have a `prototype` property. For `var x = { len: 4, breadth: 5}`, the inheritance chain would be:

- `x`
- `x`'s [[Prototype]] (which is `Object.prototype`)
- `Object.prototype`'s [[Prototype]], which is `null`

So quite short; 1, 2, or 3 depending on whether you want to count `x` and whether you want to count `null`.

> How does JavaScript internally creates automatic prototypes?

It doesn't, other than the ones defined by the spec (e.g., `Object.prototype` and such). The closest it comes is that for all `function` functions, the JavaScript engine automatically creates an object and assigns that object to the function's `prototype` property *just in case* that function is used as a constructor (via `new`). (It doesn't do this with arrow functions or generators.)

Answer (score 0):

In the browser's console, try creating an object literal:

```
const myObject = 
{
  city: 'Madrid',
  greet() 
  {
    console.log(`Greetings from ${this.city}`);
  }
}

myObject.greet(); // Greetings from Madrid
```

This is an object with one data property, `city`, and one method, `greet()`.

If you type the object's name followed by a period into the console, like `myObject.`, then the console will pop up a list of all the properties available to this object.

You'll see that as well as city and greet, there are lots of other properties!

```
__defineGetter__
__defineSetter__
__lookupGetter__
__lookupSetter__
__proto__
city
constructor
greet
hasOwnProperty
isPrototypeOf
propertyIsEnumerable
toLocaleString
toString
toValueOf
```

Try accessing one of them:

```
myObject.toString(); // "[object Object]"
```

Copy to Clipboard

It works (even if it's not obvious what `toString()` does).